# What is the best way to handle an "other" option in a select box?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm needing to implement a select box that has an "other" option. If this is selected the user should be able to type in a different option into a Text Field. My concern is for how to implement the save into the database. I'm looking for unique and efficient ways to handle this implementation.

I believe the last time I implemented this i had two columns in my table, one for the select box and one for the text field input.

Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Any reason why the textbox value must not be in the same column? Seems like you could just have your form handler use the textbox value instead of the select box value under a certain condition. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @Fareesh Vijayarangam You're right that on submit I could get the value of the textbox value and store that in the database, but when that user goes to edit that field again the select box wouldn't show it since the select box options are pulled from another database table.

Comment: In the specific case of the edit method, you could potentially write a little code that pre-selected "Other" and populated the text-box with the data in the database. You will end up writing something along the lines of this code anyway in the end when you use two columns, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a reference table that populates your select box with fields: id, item, primary. Where 'primary' is a bool indicating if it should be included in your drop down list or not.

Then when users input Other items, the items will be added to your reference table with 'primary' field being false.

The nice thing about this implementation is that it's conceptually clean - there is only one field that stores your item values, and if many of your users are adding a specific field for Other, you can just just flip the 'primary' bool to true and it will appear in your main drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some kind of a meta data table that drives your select box options, you can add logic that inserts the new "other" option into that table and then reference your newly added item's primary key in your main table that stores the form entered data.

If you don't want to muddy up the meta data table with every "other" submission, then I believe your approach is good - just a separate nullable column that stores "other" value.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this answer. I think I will explore it some more and see if it's worth it for my project. It would be a good way to fill the select box options with more from the user, but what about spam entries?

Comment: Right, well..  I'm sure there are solutions out there to minimize spam entries via form submissions (and duplicates).  google around.